# Encode file XML UTF 8 in oracle ISO database (problem with accents)

Tags: xml, oracle, encoding, utf-8, iso

A xml file is encoded utf-8.
I would like to load this file in a oracle database encoded in ISO : 
NLS_CHARACTERSET = WE8ISO8859P15.

We used this function :

```
declare
   i_aag_id  number := 3878;
   i_dir varchar2(50) := 'EXT_TAB_DIR';
   i_file varchar2(50) := 'PVAG_3878_AR.xml';
   i_type_pjs varchar2(20) := 'PVAR';
   l_clob   CLOB;
   xml_pjs XMLTYPE;
   l_bfile  BFILE := BFILENAME(i_dir, i_file);
begin
   DBMS_LOB.createtemporary (l_clob, TRUE);
   DBMS_LOB.fileopen(l_bfile, DBMS_LOB.file_readonly);
   DBMS_LOB.loadfromfile(l_clob, l_bfile, DBMS_LOB.getlength(l_bfile));
   insert into adb_ag_pjs (aag_id,aag_pjs,aag_pjs_doc,aag_pjs_archive,aag_type_pjs)
   values (1,XMLTYPE.createXML(l_clob),null,1,i_type_pjs);
end;
```

Unfortunately, accents are not load correctly :

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<pjs:Campaign Version="1.0" TrackId="C222_PVAR_3878" Name="C222_PVAR_3878" BreakdownCode="C222" Application="REALESTATE" xmlns:com="http://www.maileva.fr/CommonSchema" xmlns:spec="http://www.maileva.fr/MailevaSpecificSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:pjs="http://www.maileva.fr/MailevaPJSSchema">
<pjs:Requests>
   <pjs:Request MediaType="PAPER" TrackId="C222_PVAR_3878">
     <pjs:Recipients>
        <pjs:Internal>
           <pjs:Recipient TrackId="MLE PARE MARIE THÃ¿Â¿RÃ¿Â¿SE" Id="1">
                 [...]
```

Do you have any idea to load a xml file encoded utf-8 in a oracle iso database with accents ?
Thanks

Comment: Which output do you expect, i.e. what are these characters?

Comment: Check [XMLTYPE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/t_xml.htm#ARPLS71992) Constructor. You can pass character set id `csid` parameter to it, i.e. `NLS_CHARSET_ID('AL32UTF8')` in your case.

Comment: The characters must be TrackId="MLE PARE MARIE THÉRÈSE" instead of TrackId="MLE PARE MARIE THÃ¿Â¿RÃ¿Â¿SE".

Comment: I just try your advice with the parameter csid but it's not much better. 
"THÃ¿Â¿RÃ¿Â¿SE" become "THÃ¿RÃ¿SE"

Comment: Check also `LOADCLOBFROMFILE`, there you must also specify `csid` parameter. If you omit it then the BFILE is considered as `WE8ISO8859P15`, i.e. the characters are already converted to `¿` at `LOADCLOBFROMFILE`